# What means this error (">1") from gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting and error from gradle during compilation and I don't know what's happening.

```
annotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'main'. (n)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0 (n)
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0 (n)
+--- com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:3.3.1 (n)
\--- com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4 (n)

api - API dependencies for 'main' sources. (n)
+--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.1.4 (n)
+--- com.android.databinding:library:3.1.4 (n)
\--- com.android.databinding:adapters:3.1.4 (n)

apk - Apk dependencies for 'main' sources (deprecated: use 'runtimeOnly' instead). (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Compile dependencies for 'main' sources (deprecated: use 'implementation' instead).
No dependencies

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for 'main' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'debug'. (n)
No dependencies

debugApi - API dependencies for 'debug' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugApk - Apk dependencies for 'debug' sources (deprecated: use 'debugRuntimeOnly' instead). (n)
No dependencies

debugCompile - Compile dependencies for 'debug' sources (deprecated: use 'debugImplementation' instead). (n)
No dependencies

debugCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for 'debug' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for 'debug' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugProvided - Provided dependencies for 'debug' sources (deprecated: use 'debugCompileOnly' instead). (n)
No dependencies

debugRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for 'debug' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'debug'. (n)
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for 'main' sources. (n)
+--- unspecified (n)
+--- project CordovaLib (n)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0 (n)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.11 (n)
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3 (n)
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2 (n)
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 (n)
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1 (n)
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0 (n)
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 (n)
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0 (n)
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0 (n)
+--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0 (n)
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1 (n)
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0 (n)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0 (n)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0 (n)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0 (n)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0 (n)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0 (n)
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2 (n)
+--- com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0 (n)
+--- com.github.mancj:SlideUp-Android:2.2.8 (n)
+--- com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9 (n)
+--- com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0 (n)
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.8 (n)
+--- com.codewaves.stickyheadergrid:stickyheadergrid:0.9.6 (n)
+--- eu.electronicid.android:videoid-sdk:1.6.4 (n)
+--- io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0 (n)
+--- com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1 (n)
+--- jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1 (n)
+--- com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0 (n)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6 (n)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4 (n)
+--- com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.6 (n)
+--- com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0 (n)
+--- com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0 (n)
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0 (n)
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.8.0 (n)
+--- com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:3.3.1 (n)
+--- net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4 (n)
+--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0 (n)
+--- io.fotoapparat:fotoapparat:2.6.1 (n)
+--- ru.superjob:kotlin-permissions:1.0.3 (n)
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0 (n)
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.5 (n)
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0 (n)
\--- project everid-release_v1.4 (n)

lintChecks - Configuration to apply external lint check jar
No dependencies

lintClassPath - The lint embedded classpath
\--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.4
     +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.1.4
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.1.4
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.1.4
     |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0
     |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
     |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.18
     |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
     |    |    |    |         \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
     |    |    |    +--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.1.4
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:dvlib:26.1.4
     |    |    |    \--- com.android.tools:common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:repository:26.1.4
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0
     |    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.2.11
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12-b140109.1041
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.2.11
     |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:2.21
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:1.7.7
     |    |    |    |    \--- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.13
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1
     |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 22.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0
     |    |    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.0
     |    |    |         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.0
     |    |    |              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
     |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12
     |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6
     |    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.5
     |    |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
     |    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
     |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1
     |    |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1 -> 4.2.5
     |    |         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.1.4
     |    |    \--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.1.4
     |    |         +--- com.android.tools:common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |         \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.1.4
     |    |    \--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.1.4
     |    +--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56
     |    |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
     +--- com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.4
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
     |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.1.4
     |    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.1.4
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.1.4
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.1.4
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.1.4
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
     |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.1.4
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 (*)
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.1
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.1
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.1
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.1
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.1 (*)
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:5.1
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.1 (*)
     |    +--- it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0
     |    +--- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9
     |    \--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1
     +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.1.4 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.4
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824
     +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.1.4
     +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.4 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.4
     |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.1.4
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.1.4
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.1.4 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-kotlin:26.1.4
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.1.4
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.1.4
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.1.4
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.1
     |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.1 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.1.4
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.1
     |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-kotlin:26.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.1.4
     |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.1.4
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0 (*)
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.4
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.1.4 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.1.4
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.1.4 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0 (*)
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 (*)

mediolaAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'mediola'. (n)
No dependencies

mediolaApi - API dependencies for 'mediola' sources. (n)
No dependencies

mediolaApk - Apk dependencies for 'mediola' sources (deprecated: use 'mediolaRuntimeOnly' instead). (n)
No dependencies

mediolaCompile - Compile dependencies for 'mediola' sources (deprecated: use 'mediolaImplementation' instead). (n)
No dependencies

mediolaCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for 'mediola' sources. (n)
No dependencies

mediolaDebugAndroidTestAnnotationProcessorClasspath - Resolved configuration for annotation-processor for variant: mediolaDebugAndroidTest
No dependencies

mediolaDebugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: mediolaDebugAndroidTest


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dependencies'.
> 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I don't know how to fix it. I don't know what is the problem. Some advice please

EDIT: What is this error?? I'm lost with this :(

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':dependencies'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.registerDependencies(DependencyInspector.java:118)
        at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.afterResolve(DependencyInspector.java:173)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:371)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:353)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:341)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.afterResolve(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:491)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:474)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:459)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies.getResolutionResult(DefaultConfiguration.java:1063)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies_Decorated.getResolutionResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.internal.dependencies.AsciiDependencyReportRenderer.render(AsciiDependencyReportRenderer.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.AbstractDependencyReportTask.generate(AbstractDependencyReportTask.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.AbstractReportTask$2.generateReport(AbstractReportTask.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.internal.ReportGenerator.generateReport(ReportGenerator.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.AbstractReportTask.generate(AbstractReportTask.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 29 more
```

Comment: Meaning your task **:dependencies** has more that one exceptions.

Comment: Added the Exception in the first post